# onTimeout and is not function error using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I am trying to call an async function inside the setInterval by passing two arguments **originalDetails and filePath**. so I created a function with the name **createUser** and in the same function, I am adding the setInterval with 3 sec as finDetails() needs some delay to execute that function. I am getting the error as await self.gotUser(originalDetails) is not a function. Why I am getting this error I don't know

my code is as follows:-

```
const findDetails = require("./findDetails");

async createUser(originalDetails,filePath){
 return new Promise(async (resolve reject)=>{
  
  findDetails(filePath);

  setInterval(this.findUser,3000,originalDetails,filePath);
 })
}

async findUser(originalDetails,filePath){
 return new Promise(async (resolve reject)=>{
  // some code here

  var self=this;

  await self.gotUser(originalDetails); // I am getting error here in this part
  return resolve();
 });
}

async gotUser(originalDetails){
 return new Promise(async (resolve, reject)=>{
 let inputValue;
 // some coding part here

 return resolve();
 });
}
```

I have tried the code by writing both `self` and `this` still I'm getting the same issue

and this is my error message look likes

error message

```
/Users/servive_project/provide_service.js:300:18
      await self.gotUser(originalDetails);
                 ^

TypeError: self.gotUser is not a function
    at /Users/servive_project/provide_service.js:300:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Timeout.createUser [as _onTimeout] (/Users/servive_project/provide_service.js:288:12)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:561:11)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

getting two error at a same time

1. self.gotUser is not a function.
2. Timeout.createUser [as _onTimeout].

Comment: Not to be harsh, but you should find a tutorial that explains how promises and `async/await` work. Your use of `Promise` is superfluous, and by using a timer (I would suggest using `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`) you seem to be working around the issue that `findDetails` is asynchronous and you don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: Hi, @robertklep I have replaced setInterval with setTimeout. I have removed `return new Promise from findUser function` still getting the same issue.

Comment: You don't need to use `self` if you're using arrow functions.

Comment: yes @robertklep I removed self still getting same error

Comment: Are these regular functions, or are they methods? If they are functions, you don't use `this.` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change the way you call setInterval so you call this.findUser with this being your instance. Then you could get rid of the self trick in findUser.

```
setInterval(
  () => this.findUser(originalDetails, filePath), // use arrow function so 'this' context is still your class instance.
  3000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture your `this` outside the `promise`.

```js
async findUser(originalDetails,filePath){
 var self=this;

 return new Promise(async (resolve reject)=>{
  // some code here

  await self.gotUser(originalDetails); // I am getting error here in this part
  return resolve();
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Steve I tried this still not working.

Comment: Then perhaps `findUser` is called outside the context of `this`.  You might have to capture further up the stack.  I will update answer with another suggestion.  Oh, NM, i see you have a solution.